# Dynamically add hyphen on serial number input field

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, input-mask

I'm using JSF 2.0, jquery 1.9 and javascript. I also have RichFaces (no PrimeFaces). I have a serial number input field. The serial number has this format

ABCD-1234-EFGH-5678

It can have any combination of numbers and digits. The only restrictions are:
1) Alphanumeric
2) 16 characters exactly

Now, for user's comfort, I need to dyamically add the '-' every 4 characters (except, of course, at the very end). I have no idea if this is possible with what I have. Any ideas?

Thanks!

-EDIT-

So, I'm using the jQuery.MaskedInput.js option. Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#managerForm\\:computername1").mask("****-****-****-****",{placeholder:"Add Computer ID"});
        $("#managerForm\\:computername2").mask("****-****-****-****",{placeholder:"Add Computer ID"});
        $("#managerForm\\:computername3").mask("****-****-****-****",{placeholder:"Add Computer ID"});
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

But it's not working. The console says there's an uncaught error.

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'mask'
```

I'm importing this

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See if this Q&A helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632525/insert-dash-after-every-4th-character-in-input

Comment: possible duplicate of [How use mask in input field in JSF 2 + RichFaces 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883262/how-use-mask-in-input-field-in-jsf-2-richfaces-4)

Comment: By the way, FYI, PrimeFaces supports it out the box with `<p:inputMask>`: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inputMask.jsf